# Is it possible to train the ranker of Watson's Retrieve and Rank model on other features?

Tags: solr, ibm-watson, watson

Can I get personalized results from the R&R service? i.e. train the model using demographics and user features instead of Q&A pairs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use custom features.

Exactly how to do that is too complex to sensibly fit into an answer here, but there is a detailed explanation (with links to sample code) at https://medium.com/machine-learning-with-ibm-watson/developing-with-ibm-watson-retrieve-and-rank-part-3-custom-features-826fe88a5c63

Hope that helps!